# Selectable panel in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I´m trying to make something similar to the downloads panel of Transmission BT (here an image: http://www.transmissionbt.com/images/screenshots/Mac-Large.jpg) but I´m having some problems.
I made a JPanel with the progress bar, labels, icon and buttons and then added this panel to a container (JPanel again) but I need to make this component selectable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont you think  A table would be easier with this? It has al the functions you need. JUst create a table on a FRAME and then remove the headers so you just have the table. In this was you can easily handle what was selected..

Another way is to use a grid layout that changes on each addition and then each section of the column grid should have a panel. Each panel should have a mouse listener for a click. When clicked you just change the background color.

They are stil more ways of handling this so these are just two.

Goodluck

Comment: JTable could be a good solution, but, what I have to add into the table? Can I add the jpanel directly? And, can I interact with the buttons?

Comment: you wouldnt know until you try..try it out and see

Comment: +1 A one two two column `JTable` would work well. See also [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for a tip on coloring.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `JList` and `ListCellRenderer` to render your existing panel in a JList .

Comment: But if I use a ListCellRenderer can I click in the buttons?